# argocd: how to use plugins with crd?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I installed argocd in my cluster and now want to get the kustomize-helm example app running. So I modified the Config Map, as described in the [docs](https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps/tree/master/plugins/kustomized-helm), but I don't know how I can use this plugin in my application crd for the kustomized-helm example application. Up to now I have come up with this:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: kustomize-helm
spec:
  destination:
    name: ''
    namespace: kustomize-helm
    server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
  source:
    path: 
    - plugins/kustomized-helm
    repoURL: 'https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps'
    targetRevision: HEAD
    plugin: kustoimized-helm
  project: default
  syncPolicy:
    syncOptions:
      - CreateNamespace=true
```

When Applying the Application, I get a error, that the Validation failed.
So how can I get this example application with an Application Manifest to work?

Answer (score 1):

Have no idea how you get the definition of `application`, but correct one should be:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: kustomized-helm
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: default
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  project: default
  source:
    path: plugins/kustomized-helm
    plugin:
      name: kustomized-helm
    repoURL: https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps
```

Comment: But how do I use the kustomized-helm plugin I configured, in the manifest?

Comment: figured it out.